# Touch Bar and Visual Studio code

Tags: macos, mac, touch-bar, visual-studio-code

I am debugging a Java class with Visual Studio Code but, the  buttons on my touch bar do not work as expected except for Reset (cycle arrow) and Stop command (square). Any clue?

I have recently installed macOS Catalina and Visual Studio code version is 1.39.1.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'the icons do not work'?  What icons are you expecting to work?  Are those icons supposed to work?  What version of VS are you using?  What did you already do to fix this problem yourself?  See [ask] for tips on asking questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With version 1.40.0 the problem has been solved. Thanks to all the VS Dev Team.